# How to automate controll the broswer with js

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if there is a way for automate controll the broswer from js, i know that there are the `DOM` events but i was thinkg about something like `selenium`.

Some time ago i made a bot with `selenium` in Python and you could tell to the script to click buttons, scroll elements and other things by the `query selector`, there is a way for do the same thing in a WebApp? Something that can let you open a new broswer window, go on a site and perform some actions

Comment: yeap, read about headless browser

Comment: Headless browsers are the way to go. I suggest Puppeteer, It has a great doc and I liked using it.

Comment: tanks i will read about it !